# Sample document source - T&C's, hosting, general web?

Tags: legal, terms-of-use

One thing that's been on our list to do is getting together some T&C's, hosting documentation and just general web documents.

Are there any good sources for this? The one's I've found are a bit ropey at best.

If anyone has any idea's of any other documents that a web development/design company may need then that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it's best to [hire a lawyer](http://www.lawsociety.org.uk/home.law) who specialises in online law and have them write a TOS or T&C for you.

In the UK the [information commissioners office](http://www.ico.gov.uk/tools_and_resources.aspx) (I apologise for my government's aesthetic taste) offers advice and general help for privacy policies and some guidance about what you should and shouldn't do.

I would hope most countries offer a similar kind of service.

However a truly alarming number of my clients just copy a competitor's and change the names, I've found instances of this in the UK's Health Service and major multi-national organisations - it's dumb and often causes more problems down the road than you can imagine.

Comment: Agreed on all counts. To be honest, I've been guilty of this in the past as well. Sometimes you can't afford (or the client is too cheap) to hire a lawyer to draft a custom contract, but you should at the very least legally obtain a stock contract or template and have a lawyer go over it with you to make sure it fits with your business situation. ...oh and apology accepted; I recently used the USPTO trademark search engine, which is far worse. =P

Comment: @Lèsemajesté +1